# Bootrap carousel indicators not working on Material Design Boostrap

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, src

Hello I'm using  Angular 7 with [Material Design Bootstrap library](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/download/)

and I've Installed as they suggested through `npm`, and used the carousel, but the indicators not seems to work like JavaScript is missing, I've tried used the Content Delivery Networks (CDN) as below and it work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I don't intend using CDN for on the project but did just for troubleshooting.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of your code?